# How to change a column of a DataFrame to DateTime in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, hour

I have the following DataFrame and I want to change the column 'hour' into a DateTime format, since it has been introduced as a string.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
result=df_tott.copy()
result.head()

                popular_board_data                                        post_time_data                                         user_link                      username    hour    totalCount
0   {"boards":[{"postCount":"75","topicCount":"5",...   {"hours":[{"hour":"00:00","postCount":"12","to...   http://atariage.com/forums/user/31751-low-budg...   last        00:00   12
1   {"boards":[{"postCount":"351","topicCount":"11...   {"hours":[{"hour":"00:00","postCount":"79","to...   http://atariage.com/forums/user/4026-bomberpun...   truk        02:00   3
2   {"boards":[{"postCount":"2","topicCount":"2","...   {"hours":[{"hour":"00:00","postCount":0,"topic...   http://atariage.com/forums/user/62944-sergei27...   ets         00:00   0
```

I have tried this code, but I get a whole DateTime format with the date of today. I don't want a date, only the hour as DateTime.

```
result['date']=pd.to_datetime(result['hour'])
data=result.loc[:,['hour','totalCount']]
data=data.set_index(result.date)
data.head()
```

Output:

```
            hour    totalCount
 date       
2019-07-22  00:00   12
2019-07-22  02:00   3
2019-07-22  00:00   0
```

I want similar output but the 'date' column being in appearance like the 'hour' one but without being a string:

```
            hour    totalCount
 hour_min       
 00:00      00:00   12
 02:00      02:00   3
 00:00      00:00   0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first convert the datetimes to time object in python and then create a new Series object from array of time objects.

Try this

```
result=df_tott.copy()
result.head()
result['date']=pd.Series([obj.time() for obj in pd.to_datetime(result['hour'])])
result.date.name = 'hour_min'
data=result.loc[:,['hour','totalCount']]
data=data.set_index(result.date)
data.head()
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I get the following error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'time'